# Datanode is not starting: incompatible clusterID Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Trying to start hadoop 2.7.3 services datanode is not starting:

```
java.io.IOException: Incompatible clusterIDs in /opt/hadoop/tmp/dfs/data: namenode clusterID = CID-4808098e-de31-469d-9761-9a4558fdaf70; datanode clusterID = CID-492135f3-fc08-46f1-a574-878855ae865e
```

I already copied namenode clusterId onto datanode in tmp folder and reformat namenode. Also, I removed tmp folder, reformat and start again.

The only way to start it is deleting manually tmp foder everytime I want to start again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be formatting namenode everytime when you are starting service. Namenode should be formatted only once. The solution is to delete the temp folder,  then format the namenode and start the service. Next time whenever you are starting the service don't format the namenode bcz this step has to be performed only one time.

Comment: Ok. The problem was I formated namenode everytime I stop the services. Solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using below command

`hdfs namenode -format -clusterId`

Comment: This worked for me! Totally different context, I was setting up hdfs in docker-compose, and since I was destroying/recreating some of the containers, and using `hdfs namenode -format` sometimes, the cluster ID was sometimes getting out of sync on the datanodes and namenodes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the `tmp` folder that you need to delete to resolve this issue. Neither formatting of the datanode/namenode clusterId helps. To resolve it, follow the next sequence of actions:

1. Log in as a normal user. I assume that you have created an**hdfs** user in your linux, as it was recommended in the book by *Arun C. Murthy 'Apache Hadoop YARN'* in the beginning of the second chapter. With the help of **hdfs-site.xml** locate your **dfs.namenode.name.dir**, **fs.checkpoint.dir**, and **dfs.datanode.data.dir** folders. In my case, they all are in **/var/data/hadoop/hdfs** folder. So, do `cd /var/data/hadoop`
2. Do `sudo rm -r ./hdfs`
3. Staying in **/var/data/hadoop**, Do `sudo mkdir -p ./hdfs/nn`, `sudo mkdir -p ./hdfs/snn`, `sudo mkdir -p ./hdfs/dn`
4. From wherever you are, do `sudo chown hdfs:hadoop /var/data/hadoop/hdfs -R`
5. Log in as a **hdfs** user. In my case, it can be done as `su - hdfs`, since 'hdfs' is also a name for that user.
6. Now, format your HDFS with `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs namenode -format`

Remember, that normally formatting should be performed only once, while setting up your Hadoop environment.

At this moment, no clusterId incompatibilities should be possible, so you may proceed using your HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can delete all contents under data and namenode folders, and restart the cluster again, new ids will be assigned to data and namenode

Answer (score -2):

Try to find `clusterId` of `DataNode` in

`/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_store/hdfs/datanode/current` *(such as `CID-c9f77ebe-1f8b-4005-91cd-6abfe9443fee`)*

and use

```
./sbin/stop-all.sh<br>
hdfs namenode -format -clusterId CID-c9f77ebe-1f8b-4005-91cd-6abfe9443fee<br>
./sbin/start-all.sh<br>
```